# Java/Android: only half of the website is fetched

Tags: java, android, web, fetch

I'm going through the [Android development tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). I'm not very experienced in Java, but I find this to be a good exercise. Anyways, here is the code currently that *should* fetch me the data from a website on my Android device (pretty much downloadUrl does everything - so help me on that):

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{
            doEt(result);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        java.net.URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(100000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(150000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        //conn.disconnect();
        return total.toString();
    }
}
```

In doEt() I just print out the string I acquired. Only half of the website is in the returned String variable though. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problems:

1. 2nd half of the website is generated by javascript which httpconnection will not execute.
2. try try to print out line by line first

   ```
   while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

      total.append(line);

      Log.i("test",line);
   ```

   }

Comment: Hmm.. It does print out every line, so the website does get fetched correctly. And the problem turns out to be the IDE, thanks anyways :)